# How to replace a whole column with an array of numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I searched a lot but didn't quite find what I am looking for.

I have an array of numbers say [1, 2, 3].

and I have a dataframe:

```
   attr1  attr2
A     10     13
B     11     14
C     12     15
```

I want to replace all values of attr1 with the values in the array so that my output is

```
   attr1   attr2
A      1      13
B      2      14
C      3      15
```

I tried

```
df['attr1'] = df['attr1'] <- array
print df['attr1']
```

^ - that is setting everything to True or False

and `df[['attr1']] <- array` throws an exception

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 51, placement implies 1
```

Comment: `df['attr1'] = [1, 2, 3]` ?

Comment: I'd recommend you to delete this question and get your reputation "mana" back... ;-)

Comment: How about `df['attr1'] -= 9` :-)

Comment: Am I reading this wrong. Are you using the R assignment operator `<-`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a list containing the values:

```
df['attr1'] = [1,2,3]
```

Or if you have a bigger range on your dataframe use a [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) of values:

```
df['attr1'] = range(1,4)
```